# Is HTML5 Local Storage data stored seperated by domain

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have tried looking around about HTML5 Local Storage but I can't seem to find a straight answer.

Does the Local Storage store its objects based on Domain like cookies?

If so how do I access it from another domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain

Answer (score 2):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#security-localStorage):

> User agents must throw a `SecurityError` exception whenever any of the members of a `Storage` object originally returned by the `localStorage` attribute are accessed by scripts whose effective script origin is not the same as the origin of the `Document` of the `Window` object on which the `localStorage` attribute was accessed.

You cannot access data stored in `localStorage` from any domain other than the one that stored it there. It follows the same model as the `XMLHttpRequest` - the "same origin policy".

Comment: NB: domain !== origin, origin is _based_ upon domain.

Comment: @Alnitak - Yes, but the OP is asking specifically about access from another domain.

Comment: Yes, but from a pure DNS perspective, different subdomains of a domain are still different domains, even though they may have the same origin

Answer (score 0):

> If so how do I access it from another domain?

You cannot.

LocalStorage data is created based on the domain of the web page.  That data is then only accessible from web pages under the same domain.

Here is why this is a good idea:
Would you want a site like hackerz.pwn to be able to read/write/remove this?

```
Example (page on www.yourbank.com):
window.localStorage.setItem("user_session",  "1234567");
```

Comment: That's what I thought, I figured that would be a huge security hole. So just curious, how does StackOverflow manage to handle global authentication using localstorage, they state that it's stored under the stackauth.com domain.