# localStorage.clear() in Iframe also clear the localStorage of Main Page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, local-storage

I am working on Live Editor and use a `HTML5 localstorage` to store some important data,on my `Main Page`,

And I have an `Iframe` on my `Main Page` that is working on same domain which is used to show the result of editor, Here the problem is, whenever i write the JS code :

Like :

```
localStorage.clear();
```

To my editor and run it on my Iframe then it also clear my localStorage of Main Page.

How i Correct this problem ?

I am sending my code to `iframe` by using string,

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(Script);
```

`Script` contains a `script tag` with the `User Code` and it will run only inside iframe!
But Why my `localStorage.clear();` also `clear` Stored data of Main Page ?

Answer Will really appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less anwsered here:

[In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

localStorage is per domain.

Comment: you right,but is there any solution without using key,to prevent my localstorage of main page ?

Comment: Nope. clear() clears (with the power of lemon). You could ofc use a subdomain or other domain completly. But then you have other problems I guess.