# Scope of local storage for cordova applications

Tags: cordova, local-storage

If I'm not wrong then I know that local storage is saved in the context of browser memory. Now how is it saved?

Suppose I saved something like from one application.

```
localStorage.setItem("myvariable",'123');
```

Will it be available in other application? If two applications used the same **name** how is it separated one from the other? How applications understand that this variable is mine and this is not? 2 separate pages can use the variable set by the same application. How?

I can't find any suitable explanation and architecture regarding this issue.

Comment: may be this links will help your cause. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain), [link2](http://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding and the below links the localstorage is domain based.
Refer link [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain), [link2](http://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/).

i.e Any application that refer to the same domain `www.domain.com` will have access to the localstorage set by it.

`2 separate pages can use the variable set by the same application. How?`

Separate pages will be able to access the localstorage variables as per the above rule if the belong to the **same** domain.
The locatstorage is implemented by the browser which provides you the APIs for accessing/manipulating the localstorage.

Even though the above explanation is for a browser APP, the rule still holds true for cordova APP, as the cordova APP is based on a Webview.

Comment: Cordova apps doesn't have domains, then how local storage is separated? How browser knows that this comes from app 1 and this comes from app 2!