# localStorage not triggering from multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have three separate pages/tabs.

1) PageA sets localstorage with key "data"   - **works**

2) PageB gets localstorage of key "data"  - **works**

3) PageC set localstorage with key "data"   - **works**

4) PageB  gets localstorage with key "data"    **NOT WORKING** listener not triggered

(I've tried localStorage.clear  before setting 'data' to no avail. Also tried
   using a different "key" to no avail)

pageA

```
localStorage.setItem("data", "first");
```

pageB

```
  //set listener
 if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("storage", handler, false);
 } 
 else {
    window.attachEvent("onstorage", handler);
 };

 function handler(e) {  
 //works form pageA not pageC. Nothing is in console.
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));   
 }
```

pageC

```
localStorage.setItem("data", "second");
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain

Comment: @harmonickey That does not help whatsoever.

Comment: All pages are same domain and port.

Comment: I just tried this, and it works for me. is it possible that Page C's code is executed before Page B's?

Comment: I just tried this as well and it works as intended.