# How to prevent passing HTML5 local storage data between two or more different applications which were deployed at the same container?

Tags: javascript, html, session, local-storage, html5-history

i have a big deal with user session monitoring.
I need to kill session after closing last application tab or after browser closing.

So, this work was performed. I have developed small library for working with local storage and session storage and i developed mechanism for monitoring of opened browser tabs.

Just simple object with tab counter.

```
{
    "session_instance_count" : 0
}
```

And simple methods for writing this object to localstorage:

```
SessionMonitor.prototype.writeValueByKeyToLS = function (key, value){
   var own = this;
   own.getLocalStorageInstance().setItem(key, value);
};

SessionMonitor.prototype.getLocalStorageInstance = function () {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'];
};
```

But after deploying another application to Tomcat i have found serious troubles with local storage. 
All stored values from first application were available in second application.

I stored some data on http://localhost:8080/app1 this data will be available on http://localhost:8080/app2

App1 sending request to open App2 with some parameters

*Note:* I do not have access to modify source code of second application.

**This is my question:**

How to prevent passing  HTML5 local storage data between two or more different applications which were deployed at the same container?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

Comment: Unfortunately no.
Origin policy is the same.
Domain pattern for applications is identical.
localStorage.key(0) return same key value for all deployed applications

Comment: Yes, that is the point. If you want “different” localstorages, then use different domains.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with local storage was removed, because it's not provide possibilities for set data separately between applications inside one container with same domain pattern.
I have checked solution with port configuring inside tomcat/conf/server.xml
So we can set different ports to all deployed application. Or we can register one more port for applications

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8086" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="8444" />
```

http://localhost:8080/app2  with  http://localhost:8086/app1

Local storages will be unique. 
But i can't use this solution, because customer don't want this.

I found one more solution: relation between server side and client side.

Just generating unique window.name and storing it inside server session.
I hope, that it will be helpfull for somebody.