# sessionStorage with document.domain

Tags: javascript

According to the spec, I should be able to set the document.domain to my root domain and thus have subdomains share sessionStorage.  But I can't seem to get that to work.  Is that no longer allowed?  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#relaxing-the-same-origin-restriction

```
// set the document domain to the top level
let hostParts = location.hostname.split('.').reverse();
if (hostParts.length > 1)
    document.domain = `${hostParts[1]}.${hostParts[0]}`;

this.sessionId = window.sessionStorage.getItem('hplrSn');
if (!this.sessionId) this.sessionId = generateId();
```

The above code will generate a new Id for both `site1.dn.domain.com` and `site2.dn.domain.com`

Comment: Please include the code in question.

Comment: @gyre added a sample of the code I'm trying to use.

Comment: I think you have missed a dot at the beginning, i.e. `document.domain = .${hostParts[1]}.${hostParts[0]}` so it's set to `.domain.com` (I'm not sure it will work, but it fullfills the "prefixed by a U+002E FULL STOP (.)" requirement).

Comment: @pawel it tells me that `.domain.com` is not a suffix of `site1.dn.domain.com` :(

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:  [In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

It work for page `www.a.com/page1` and `www.a.com/page2`, but not for your use case: sessionstorage for `www.a.a.com` and `www.b.a.com` is not shared.

You should try `Cookie`

Comment: Even that page talks about `relaxing` the rule with the use of `document.domain` but I can't get that to work at all.  Maybe I should try `Cookie` but I really want to isolate it to the lifetime of the window/tab, not the browser (so if you have two windows open, they should get their own ID)