# How to delete localstroage in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

I keep array localstorage. I want to delete an element from the array list on another page. My code is below but delete function does not work  why?

**push.js**

```
existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntries"));
if (existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];
entry = {
         "adi":path,
        };
localStorage.setItem("entry", JSON.stringify(entry));
existingEntries.push(entry);
localStorage.setItem("allEntries", JSON.stringify(existingEntries));
```

**delete.js**

```
delete: function (e) {
  var del = e.itemData.adi //The information of the clicked element is retrieved.
  for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {
    if (dataSource[i].adi == del) { dataSource.splice(i, 1); }
  }
  // insert the new stringified array into LocalStorage
  localStorage.getItem("allEntries") = 
  JSON.stringify(existingEntries);
}
```

Comment: What does not work? You expect to get what and you are getting what?

Comment: Was `dataSource = []` ever declared?

Comment: That is not deleted. Still standing on screen @onetwo12

Comment: No, does not it have to be a array?@zer00ne

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataSource = JSON.parse(localStorage.dataSource); //whatever data you want
var del = e.itemData.adi //The information of the clicked element is retrieved.
for (var i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {
 if(del === persons[i].name){  //look for match with name
    dataSource.splice(i, 1);
   break;  //exit loop since you found the person
 }
    localStorage.getItem("allEntries") = JSON.stringify(existingEntries); // insert the new stringified array into LocalStorage
}
```

Comment: hi,The change only happens in delete.js. There is no general change

Comment: i think this link will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain