# A-Frame & ar.js: Multiple markers & boxes

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

Is there any proof of concept of how to implement multiple AR markers w/ A-Frame?

Ex. Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8WEGGbLWlA

[image]

The first video in this post from Alexandra Etienne is the effect I’m aiming for (multiple distinct AR "markers" with distinct content): https://medium.com/arjs/area-learning-with-multi-markers-in-ar-js-1ff03a2f9fbe

I’m a bit unclear if when using multiple markers they need to be close to each-other/exist in the same camera view

This example from the ar.js repo uses multiple markers but they're all of different types (ie one is a Hiro marker, one is a Kanji marker, etc): https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/examples/multiple-independent-markers.html

Comment: The multiple independent marker example that you linked to works fine.... so you want the Aframe scene to render on each of multiple copies of the same marker image?

Comment: Should have been more clear-- I'd like to use the same marker type (ie qr code of some kind) but each has different content within them (ie a qr marker with data 123456789 and a qr marker with data 987654321)

Comment: With that example, the number of unique tags appears to be limited by how many different tag types exist

Comment: QR code example (scan and then use Hiro): https://medium.com/arjs/ar-code-a-fast-path-to-augmented-reality-60e51be3cbdf

Comment: this would work, too: you could create QRcodes with links like example.com/ar.html?id=123 which create different models on the same AR marker like Hiro. The obvious limitation is that users need to rescan the QRcode on every marker.

Comment: there is this multiple-independent-markers.html for A-Frame, is there an example for Three.js?

Answer (score 4):

tldr: working glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-ar-area).
 Learn the area (the image is in the assets), click the accept button, and toggle the marker helpers.

Now, a bit of details:

### 1) Loading saved area data

Upon initialisation, when `ar.js` detects, that you want to use the `area` marker preset, it tries to grab a localStorage reference:

```
localStorage.get("ARjsMultiMarkerFile")
```

The most important data there is an array of pairs {markerPreset, url.patt} which will be used to create the `area`. 
**Note**: By default it's just the hiro marker.

### 2) Creating an area data file

When you have `debugUIEnabled` set to `true`:

```
<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: true'>
```

There shows up a button "Learn-new-marker-area".
At first glance it redirects you to a screen where you can save the area file.
There is one but: **by default the loaded learner site is on another domain**.

Strictly speaking: `ARjs.Context.baseURL = 'https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/`

Any data saved there won't be loaded on our website, for [local storage is isolated per origin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201249/2425787).

To save and use the marker area, you have to create your own `learner.html`. It can be identical to the [original](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/examples/multi-markers/examples/learner.html), just keep in mind you have to keep it on the same domain.

To make the debugUI button redirect the user to **your** learner html file, you need to set

```
ARjs.AnchorDebugUI.MarkersAreaLearnerURL = "myLearnerUrl.html"
```

before the `<a-marker>`s are initialized. Just do it in the `<head>`.

---

Once on the learner site, make sure the camera sees all the markers, and approve the learning.

It should look like this:
[image]

Once approved, you will be redirected back to your website, the area file will be loaded, and the data will be used.

Comment: my simple glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-ar-area?path=index.html:18:0)

Comment: Marker learner is working again. Check out:
https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/283#issuecomment-507312601

Comment: @droid001 Thanks for the info, i'll retry my steps and post the results !

Comment: @droid001 I've updated my anwser though the solution seems to be more suitable for a medium tutorial than SO answer :P

Comment: Could you update the first link (`tldr: working glitch here.`) which only leads to a .png?

Comment: @droid001 snap, it got mixed up when i was removing the old anwser. I've updated the link !

Answer (score 1):

As @mnutsch stated, AR.js does what you want.

You can display two different models on two different markers. If the camera doesn't see one of the markers the model vanishes (or stays where it was last, depending on your implementation.

The camera doesn't need to see both.

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i21xt76ijrsv1jh/Screenshot%202018-08-20%2011.25.22.png?dl=0

Project:
https://curious-electric.com/w/experiments/aframe/ar-generic/

Also, unlike Vuforia, there is no 'extended tracking' - once the code is out of sight, you can't track anymore.

Comment: He wants to use multiple markers as one. You should be able to create the "area" with "area-learning". Its supposed to be more stable than a single marker.