# AR.js: Multiple markers for increased stability?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I have been working around with AR.js so far and am pretty amazed by its capabilities. There is, however, something I've wanted to do and haven't yet figured out: Is it possible to define several (different) markers and use them for the placement of a single object?

The motivation behind this is that AR.js requires quite large markers, otherwise the item tremors in the camera view. Could this be circumvented by using several smaller markers in a specified offset and place the item, for example, in the center of them?

Comment: ar.js should support using mutiple markers, yet i couldn't get them to work, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850930/a-frame-ar-js-multiple-markers-boxes) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A-Frame & ar.js: Multiple markers & boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850930/a-frame-ar-js-multiple-markers-boxes)