# Any way to handle more than one multimarker area in AR.js / A-Frame?

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js, jsartoolkit

I'm trying to set-up more than one multi-marker area in AR.js with A-Frame. The idea is to have 4 pattern markers laid out as a square frame for each content.
[The AR.js multimarker examples](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/tree/master/three.js/examples/multi-markers/examples) make use of the learner to put the pose matrix data in the URL. Is there any way to generate different multimarker files and assign them to each a-marker? I've attached some sample code to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<a-scene>
<a-marker preset="area" id="first">
...
</a-marker>
<a-marker preset="area" id="second">
...
</a-marker>
<a-marker preset="area" id="third">
...
</a-marker>
<a-camera />
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the name of the localstorage item with the configuration object is hardcoded [here](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/src/new-api/arjs-anchor.js#L61-L62).

I was able to get multiple marker areas, but i had to modify the ar.js code. The result is in [this glitch](https://aframear-multiplecustomarea.glitch.me/), the markers are in the assets.

**First**, I had to create and keep the multimarker configuration objects (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52017472/2425787) SO thread, or [this](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/283) ar.js issue on custom area markers). Before creating the scene i set the configs:

```
// the name will correspond to the marker id
var oneMarker = { /* paths, pose matrices, etc. */ }
localStorage.setItem("oneMarkerFile", JSON.stringify(oneMarker));
```

**Second** - I've modified the [Arjs.Anchor object](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/src/new-api/arjs-anchor.js#L56-L62) - so it won't read a predefined localStorageObject:

```
// originally ARjsMultiMarkerFile
let markerId = markerParameters.markerName + "MarkerFile"
```

**Third** - I have to pass the `markerParameters.markerName` somehow. The Arjs.Anchor object is created in the [arjs-anchor component init function](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/aframe/src/component-anchor.js#L101-L104). With one line you can set the above `markerName` property:

```
markerParameters.markerName = _this.el.id
// anywhere before instantiating the anchor (new ARjs.Anchor(arSession, markerParameters))
```