# Anchor 3D model in place using multiple markers in ar.js?

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm displaying a gltf model using ar.js using a marker and overlaying it over a physical item (Steel Beam), this works well if the person stays in one position further away with the single marker in view, but the requirement is to be able to walk along side and around the physical object, with the 3D model staying anchored in place.

Is there a way to use multiple markers together to anchor a 3D model in place?

So far in my testing the model either disappears when the marker is lost, or the model stays frozen in place on screen (moving with the device as the person moves). I tried "group" marker examples as well however they don't appear to work in this scenario either, the model jumps around to each marker as they become visible.

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51850930/a-frame-ar-js-multiple-markers-boxes) (also check out [this](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/283))?