# How change the localStorage from my api domain?

Tags: javascript

I use login with facebook in nodejs. I set facebook return url to: api.example.com/api/return.

I also store the token in localStorage and I don't want to use cookie.

when I return to api.mysite.com/api/return I make sure if it success, then I response with 200 and script: `window.location = 'https://example.com'`.

The problem is I want to change the localStorage in https://example.com, but I'm in `https://api.mysite.com`.

Is there a way to change the localStorage in https://example.com, from https://api.example.com?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In HTML5, is the localStorage object isolated per page/domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201239/in-html5-is-the-localstorage-object-isolated-per-page-domain)

Comment: No! there is no direct way to do that currently. There will be a lot of work that needs to done to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [cross-storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage).
Basically, the concept is that there are **hubs** and **clients**:

1. **hubs**: reside on any server, interact directly with LocalStorage API.
2. **clients**: load the hub using an embedded iframe, and post messages, interact with data.